# keras custom layer seems to be receiving input from other layer only at model.fit

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

I have built a model that has to deal with data aggregation via a custom layer (the custom is an OWA layer that performs just fine and has been tested individually).

Anyway, the model has a series of Lambda keras layers with tf.gather inside in order to select some of the data according to its indices in order to perform a OWA aggregation. The model builds and compiles just fine even the graphviz scheme of it is fine.

But when runnig model.fit (the model training performs just fine without this part on it) i get an error indicating that the input received by the OWA layer 7 has an incorrect shape (None, 12, 4, 12) instead of  (None, 12, 4, 3). Wile performing the same opperations with the same layers manually the received shape was the right one (None, 12, 4, 3). Precisely, the received shape corresponds to the OWA layer 8. I cannot think of another explanation other than that model.fit is malfunctioning in some way that the the connections between layers are bad.

The model graph [layers of the model graphviz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkuZ6.png), the error
[eror while fitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOQPh.png), and the model construction: [model layers creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goY8n.png)